# Doubt w/ Inner Products: Ramakrishnan's "Fourier Analysis on Number Fields", Section 3.2

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

In Section 3.2 of this textbook (pg. 91), Ramakrishnan considers the function $\phi(s) = (\rho(s)[x],x)$, where $(\cdot,\cdot)$ denotes an inner product and $\rho$ denotes a representation of a top. group $G$ in the space of unitary operators of a Hilbert space $H$. So, $s \in G, x \in H$.

He writes...

$$\sum_{i,j=1}^n \phi(s_j^{-1}s_i)z_j\bar{z_i} = \sum_{i,j=1}^n (\rho(s_j^{-1}s_i)[x],x)z_j\bar{z_i} =_{(2)} \sum_{i,j=1}^n(\rho(s_i)[x],\rho(s_j)[x])z_j\bar{z_i}$$

$$=_{(3)} (\sum_{i=1}^n \rho(s_j)(z_jx),\sum_{j=1}^n \rho(s_i)(z_ix))$$

**Question** (2) is because $\rho(s_j)$ is unitary + can be cancelled with its inverse since its a representation. **However, I am unable to see why equality (3) is true.**

**My reasoning so far...**
I know that, for a complex inner product, $(ax,by)=(x,y)a\bar{b}$ for complex constants $a,b$. Also, that it is conjugate symmetric, i.e. $(x,y)=\overline{(y,x)}$ (Ramakrishnan uses this assumption here, at least). Therefore, I can see the following:

$$(\rho(s_i)[x],\rho(s_j)[x])z_j\bar{z_i} = \overline{(\rho(s_j)[x],\rho(s_i)[x}]) z_j\bar{z_i} = \overline{(\rho(s_j)[x],\rho(s_i)[x]) \bar{z_j}z_i}$$

But this is not the same as what we desire.

Comment: Is it possible there is a typo here and the index in the first sum should be $j$ and the index in the second sum should be $i$?

Comment: You don't say what the textbook is, but physicists for instance have their inner products conjugate-linear in the first position and linear in the second.  You may want to look at the conventions.

Comment: @yoyo Textbook is in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answer was found, so I am not sure